# Android AutoCompleteTextView width

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, android-jetpack

I am following this guide to create a dropdown menu:
https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus

So I have a `TextInputLayout` containing a custom subclass of `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`.

I override `convertSelectionToString` to show a shorter version of the selected item:

```java
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        if (selectedItem instanceof CountryInfo) {
            CountryInfo country = (CountryInfo) selectedItem;
            return country.toShortString();
        }
        return super.convertSelectionToString(selectedItem);
    }
```

You can see below what it looks like. However what I want is for the upper text input box to wrap only the shortened text, while the dropdown expands wide enough to show its contents.

#### What I have

[image: screenshot]

#### What I want (mock)

[image]

Comment: Update: there's no way to do this with the standard view, but I was able to make my own solution. See the changes to `CountryListSpinner` in this PR:
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/1904

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the width of the view based on the selection of the item in it.

I guess your custom view has some method like setText, right?
And after that you  can set the width to wrap content of the currently selected view. So something like this:

```
CharSequence selectedText = convertSelectionToString(selectedObject);
yourView.setText(selectedText);

// ConstraintLayout is mentioned here, but it can be any layout
yourView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
yourView.invalidate(); // might be needed to use
```